# Power output by an RF switch

Tags: power, rf

I am using the PE42423MLBA-Z RF switch.
I am trying to get an idea of the output current given by this chip.

Now E = Sqrt(P)*R. E =5V, R = 50Ohms.
So, P = 10mW.

But, this is a switch, that merely routes power/signal with almost no loss in efficiency. Hence, in ideal cases ,Pout = Pin.
[image: power data]

Pin (max) = 38.5dBm, which roughly translates to 3W or so. How am I getting 2 different power ratings ?

Comment: According to my calculation, 38.5 dBm equals 7.1 W !

Comment: oops. my bad. but then how am i getting 2 different wattage ?

Comment: You mean different values for 2.4 GHz and 6 GHz ?

Comment: No both are values I am culculating for 2.4GHz.

Comment: E = Sqrt(P)*R. E =5V, R = 50Ohms. So, P = 10mW.
While from the input of 38.5dBm we get approx 7W. How so?

Comment: Where is your 5 V coming from ? For 38.5 dBm the signal would be 27 Vpeak.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37156/discussion-between-fakemoustache-and-board-man).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that this chip can switch an RF signal of up to 38.5 dBm, which is 27 V peak in 50 ohm, even though it is controlled from a single 5 V supply.

So the 5 V is not related in any way to the maximum RF power the chip can handle.

I am curious how they do that because this is not something you can easily do in most RF ICs.

Update:
It appears that the manufacturer of this chip has a list of [their patents](http://www.psemi.com/company/trademarks-patents) on their website. Number 6,804,502 *"Switch Circuit and Method of Switching Radio Frequency Signals"* seems applicable. Find it on [Google patent search](http://www.google.com/patents/US6804502).

So what they do is that they series connect several MOSFETs to handle the voltage (that 27 Vpeak). And an on-chip capacitive voltage multiplier to make the voltages needed to control the gates of those MOSFETs. Clever ! :-)